# How can I make this stack code use less memory? (C lang)

Tags: memory, stack, clang

```
#include<stdio.h>

int tp=-1;

void push(int arr[],int value)
{
    arr[++tp]=value;
}

void pop(int arr[])
{
    if(size()==0)
    {
        puts("-1");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d\n",arr[tp--]);
}

int size()
{
    return tp+1;
}

void empty()
{
    if(size()==0)puts("1");
    else puts("0");
}

int top(int arr[])
{
    if(size()==0)
    {
        puts("-1");
        return;
    }   
    printf("%d\n",arr[tp]);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10000];
    unsigned int i,repeat;
    char command[6];

    scanf("%d",&repeat);                //repeating
    for(i=0;i<repeat;i++)
    {
    scanf("%s",command);
    switch(command[0])
    {
        case 'p':
            if(command[1]=='u')         //push
            {
                int value;
                scanf("%d",&value);
                push(arr,value);
            }
            else pop(arr);              //pop. if stack is empty, output -1
            break;
        case 's':
            printf("%d\n",size());      //print size of stack
            break;
        case 'e':
            empty();                    //if stack is empty, print 1. if not, print 0.
            break;
        case 't':
            top(arr);                   //print value that is on top of stack. if stack is empty, print -1
            break;
    }
}
```

}

i wanna make this code use less memory...
this code uses 1116KB,
but a code with same algorithm uses 1000KB.
How can i make this code use less memory?

this code works like this -

this code has 5 commands:

1.push X : adds X in the stack

2.pop : Removes an item from the stack and print it.

3.size : print the number of elements of the stack

4.empty : if this stack is empty, print 1. if not print 0

5.top : print the item that is on the top of the stack

steps

1. input value (amount of repeat loop)
2. input command
3. profit!!

Answer (score 0):

There can be several solutions to this issue. Since, you are using a static array and a top variable to keep a track of your stack's last element, you end up with the same space complexity of the algorithm as the size of array remains the same everytime.

Thus, you should use dynamic memory allocation while adding any element to the stack, this refers to the use of malloc or calloc functions in C to assign memory from heap everytime you add a location. Whereas using free function to pop an element and free memory assigned to it.

Here's the code for implementation of a stack using linked lists:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node
{
   int data;
   struct Node *next;
}*top = NULL;

void push(int);
void pop();
void display();

void main()
{
   int choice, value;
   printf("1. Push\n2. Pop\n3. Display\n4. Exit\n");
   while(1){
      printf("Enter your choice: ");
      scanf("%d",&choice);
      switch(choice){
     case 1: printf("\nEnter value to insert: ");
         scanf("%d", &value);
         push(value);
         break;
     case 2: pop(); break;
     case 3: display(); break;
     case 4: exit(0);
     default: printf("\nWrong selection!!! \n");
      }
   }
}
void push(int value)
{
   struct Node *newNode;
   newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   newNode->data = value;
   if(top == NULL)
      newNode->next = NULL;
   else
      newNode->next = top;
   top = newNode;
   printf("\nInsertion is Success!!!\n");
}
void pop()
{
   if(top == NULL)
      printf("\nStack is Empty!!!\n");
   else{
      struct Node *temp = top;
      printf("\nDeleted element: %d", temp->data);
      top = temp->next;
      free(temp);
   }
}
void display()
{
   if(top == NULL)
      printf("\nStack is Empty!!!\n");
   else{
      struct Node *temp = top;
      while(temp->next != NULL){
     printf("%d--->",temp->data);
     temp = temp -> next;
      }
      printf("%d",temp->data);
   }
}
```

You can also validate the use of memory at [codechef's online IDE](https://ideone.com/QEyZmP) as it is using 9432 KB.